# Get list of all holiday calendars via google calendar api

Tags: javascript, google-calendar-api

can I retrieve a list of all available holiday iCals? And if it is possible, can I filter that via API?

Because the name is something like this

```
en.usa#holiday
```

or better

```
nl.dutch#holiday
```

it's hard to code that dynamically. Normally I have either the country name or the code (two letter or three letter) but the written-out language name just in very rare cases.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: It is a partial answer. The best approach would be is subscribing to all countries' holiday calendar since searching public calendar is not available using UI or in the API (try Gear>Calendar Settings>Calendar>Browse Interesting calendars). Then use [CalendarList: list](https://developers.google.com/calendar/v3/reference/calendarList/list), to list as calendars you own or subscribed on to then filter it manually getting only holiday calendar. Hope this helps.

Comment: Okay, thanks. It's a pity that google hasn't implemented it yet. But I'm not sure if they will do it in the future…